# Can't Open Word File With Space

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-script

I use sikuli to open doc file

```
cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE c:\report\Monthly report 2016.doc"

openApp(cmd)
```

It can't be opened but when i renamed no space to Monthly.doc it can be opened

Comment: try to quote the filename?

Answer (score 1):

First, App.open is advised as openApp is deprecated.
Regardless though this is a command line type problem. It is all about wrapping the quotes. Both should work:

```
App.open(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" "c:\report\Monthly report 2016.doc"')

openApp(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" "c:\report\Monthly report 2016.doc"')
```

Small reference on quoting:
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+faq/1739

Answer (score 0):

try insert '\' before the space..